# Insert index after every 2nd row that lists down total of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
Ind1                Ind2         M     F
Business Analyst    1-2 years    50    55
Business Analyst    10-20 years  47    23
DBA Engineer        1-2 years    31    12
DBA Engineer        10-20 years  21    10
```

I want to calculate the total count for M and F individually and insert it after the end of a unique occupation entry (in this case the 2nd row). The data frame is multi indexed (Ind1 and Ind2).
So my end data frame should be:

```
Ind1                Ind2         M     F
Business Analyst    1-2 years    50    55
Business Analyst    10-20 years  47    23
Total               Not required 97    78
DBA Engineer        1-2 years    31    12
DBA Engineer        10-20 years  21    10
Total               Not required 52    22
```

How can I do it in pandas? I haven't been able to code this out properly.

Note: The new rows should be part of index (i.e. inside it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to `groupby` the dataframe on `Ind1` and aggregate using `sum`, then append this aggregated dataframe to `df` and `sort` the values on `Ind1`:

```
df1 = df.append(df.groupby('Ind1', as_index=False).sum()\
        .assign(Ind2='Not Required')).sort_values('Ind1', ignore_index=True)

df1.loc[df1['Ind2'].eq('Not Required'), 'Ind1'] = 'Total'
```

Another similar approach but here we process each grouped frame in `df` seperately, followed by concatenating all the grouped frames:

```
f = lambda g: g.append({'Ind1': 'Total', 'Ind2': 'Not Required', **g[['M','F']].sum()}, ignore_index=True)
df1 = pd.concat([f(g) for _, g in df.groupby('Ind1')], ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
               Ind1          Ind2   M   F
0  Business Analyst     1-2 years  50  55
1  Business Analyst   10-20 years  47  23
2             Total  Not Required  97  78
3      DBA Engineer     1-2 years  31  12
4      DBA Engineer   10-20 years  21  10
5             Total  Not Required  52  22
```

Comment: Can you tell what ** indicates at `**g[["M", "F"]]` at the second code block?

Comment: @shiv_90 `**` is to unpacking operator which is used here to unpack and merge the series `g[["M", "F"]].sum()` with dictionary `{'Ind1': 'Total', 'Ind2': 'Not Required'}`. So for example the resulting dictionary for `Business Analyst` will be  `{'Ind1': 'Total', 'Ind2': 'Not Required', 'M': 97, 'F': 78}`

Comment: Not necessary. But why is the first code block not adding the `Total` row at the expected location? For example, if I have six such rows, then the first code adds `Total` to every third row. Whereas the second block works as expected. Why is that? Both versions of code should return the same output.

Comment: @shiv_90 Let's discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225866/ds5)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a for loop:

```
df['index'] = range(len(df))
for i in range(1, len(df), 2):
    df.loc[len(df)] = ['Total', 'Not required', df.iloc[[i-1, i]]['M'].sum(), df.iloc[[i-1, i]]['F'].sum(), i + 0.1]
df = df.sort_values(by='index').drop('index', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
               Ind1          Ind2   M   F
0  Business Analyst     1-2 years  50  55
1  Business Analyst   10-20 years  47  23
2             Total  Not required  97  78
3      DBA Engineer     1-2 years  31  12
4      DBA Engineer   10-20 years  21  10
5             Total  Not required  52  22
```

Comment: When running the for loop, I'm getting `Cannot set a row with mismatched columns` error.